# Holding a key resetting after subroutine trigger

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to get a key to be held and then a subroutine ran at a certain interval, but the key stops being held after the subroutine runs.

```
F1::
alt := not alt
if (alt)
    {
        Click down
        SetTimer, Sell, 6000
    }
    else
    {
        Click up
        SetTimer, Sell, off
    }
Return
Sell:
    alt = false
    SendRaw test
    Sleep 50
    Send {Enter}
    alt = true
Return
```

Comment: Using your script as-is in Paint (with Pencil tool) worked without problems (of course, typing "test" and pressing enter has no effect while drawing). What program are you using it in? Also, what is the purpose of the `alt = false` and `alt = true` in your subroutine since it's only separated by 50ms?

Comment: I'm using it in a game, hold the mouse button, then submit a command (in the Sell routine). The command opens a new menu to run. Then it holds the mouse button again.